# Prevent Text Input expanding in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, forms, stylesheet

I am having a problem with an input field in IE.  The code is for a portlet and widths need to be dynamic as the user can place the portlet on any of the three columns in the page which all have different widths.  As always it works fine in FF but not in IE.  In order to make the width dyanaic I have set width="100%".  Data to populate the text input comes from a DB.  When the page is rendered if there is a long URL the text input expands to fill the contents in IE but in FF it just stays the same width (ie 100% of the TD that it lives in).  How can I stop IE from changing the width in order to fit the contents.  Setting the width to a fixed width of 100px fixes the issue but I need to have the width as a percentage in order to accommodate the layout of the portlet wherever it is put in on the page.

I have tried overflow:hidden and word-wrap:break-word but I cant get either to work.  Here is my input code and style sheets

```
<td class="right" >
    <input type="text" class="validate[custom[url]]" value="" id="linkText" name="communicationLink"  maxlength="500" maxsize="100" />
</td>

    .ofCommunicationsAdmin input {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#333333;
    overflow:hidden;
    }



   .ofCommunicationsAdmin #linkText { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:100%; 
    border:1px 
    #cccccc solid; 
    background:#F4F7ED 
    top repeat-x;
    }

.ofCommunicationsAdmin td.right {
   vertical-align: top;   
   text-align: left;   
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to an example page, or at least a screenshot of correct vs incorrect (FF vs IE)?

Comment: I cannot provide a link as it is an internal app, I have a screenshot but just realised that I cannot upload it and I do not have access to image hosting from work either!  Basically in IE my entire table triples in width when there is a URL in one of the form fields.  In FF it keeps the with the same and you have to put your cursor in the text input and scroll to the right to see the text.  The FF behaviour is what I want.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little late to this party but I just ran across this problem myself.

If I understand the problem correctly, your markup looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Whatever</td>
    <td><input /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the input is in the table. Also, in your CSS, you're setting the input to have a percentage-based width. However, when you put so much text into the input that it expands past that visible width, the table expands to fit the container.

It's really easy to fix this, but so random that there's not a lot of help out there for it. The solution is to add this to your CSS (I added it to my reset.css).

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

You can make it IE specific if you want to, but it doesn't do anything bad to the other browsers (that I've noticed).

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried overflow:hidden and word-wrap:break-word

Yeah, they won't do anything useful on an input.

> In order to make the width dyanaic I have set width="100%"

That should work, but the parent table needs to be constrained to a width and `table-layout: fixed` otherwise the [auto-table-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout) algorithm comes into play, which is complicated, a bit broken, and probably won't do what you want.

This is an example of how I layout liquid forms. Note the use of the box-sizing hack to make the edges of different types of control line up exactly in browsers that support it (not IE6-7).

```
<table class="form">
    <col class="label" /><col class="input" />
    <tr>
        <td><label for="foo">Foo</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" value="bar" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

table.form { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
col.label { width: 6em; }   /* let col.input have the rest of the width */
table.form input, table.form textarea, table.form select {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried to implement the styles you gave but it is still doing the same thing, stretching out the entire portlet to be 2/3 of the size of the screen (The entire portlet should only take up 1/4 of the screen)

Comment: It doesn't for me. Could you post a test-case including the outer wrapper that demonstrates the failure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me for?

Comment: I'm saying we can't guess why your attempt to implement this is failing without the code. I have no clue about what your wrapping portlet stuff looks like because you haven't posted the HTML it produces. The example works for me; if we can't reproduce the problem we can't fix it.

Comment: There is far too much code to post up.  I suppose I was looking for some sort of a quick way to tell IE to stop changing the input.  I have managed to put a hack together that user jQuery to calculate the required width and set the exact with on a style that all the inputs use.  It works fine but it would obviously be better if IE just worked like it was supposed to.  Thanks for helping tough!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: `INPUT {overflow-x:hidden; }`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why  ? The question is in the title or "How can I stop IE from changing the width in order to fit the contents", not sure how this cannot be an answer, I had the same problem on IE6 and fixed it in this way.

Comment: Then you should add the complete working code snippet.

Comment: The snippet is the one I wrote. The only thing clear in this question is the title, however it is on the top on google when searching for this problem, that affects only IE6, IE7 apparently fixed this in 2006. There is no accepted answer and one answer saying overflow  "won't do anything useful on an input", instead, overflow-x worked for me, why ? I don't want to know ;-) I am using Bootstrap + an integration for IE6, is a complex setup, like Caroline I cannot write it here.